# не удаётся отправить данные в mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь отправить данные в базу mysql. Если везде цифры, то отправляется всё нормально, но если в переменных есть английские буквы он ни чего не отправляет

**Код самой страницы**

```
    session_start();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Регистрация</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="vendor/reg.php" method="post">
    <label>Логин</label>
    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="введите логин" value="">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="введите почту" value="">
    <label>Пароль</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="введите пароль" value="">
    <label>Подтверждение пароля</label>
    <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="введите пароль повторно" value="">
    <button>Зарегистрироваться</button>
    <p>
         <a href="index.php" >Авторизоваться</a>
    </p>

        <?php
        if($_SESSION['message']){
            echo ' <p class="msg">'.$_SESSION['message'].'</p>';
        }
            unset($_SESSION['message']);
        ?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**код для проверки и отправки данных**

````
    session_start();
    require_once 'connect.php';

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];

    if ($password === $password2){



        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `login`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, $login,  $email,  $password)");
        header('Location: ../index.php');

    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Пароли не совпадают!';
        header('Location: ../register.php');


    }```
````

Comment: Используйте привязку переменных https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php а не их непосредственную подстановку в текст запроса. Кроме того после каждого запроса проверяйте на ошибки выполнения и выводите их, что бы в нештатных ситуациях понимать, что происходит

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в  `` mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `login`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, $login,  $email,  $password)"); ``

переменные взять в кавычки

`` mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `login`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '$login',  '$email',  '$password')"); ``